# Extracting some numbers from a byte data

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, urllib, urlopen

I am new to web-scraping. After scraping some websites using these lines:

```
x1 = urllib.request.urlopen('somewebsite1').read()
x2 = urllib.request.urlopen('somewebsite2').read()
x3 = urllib.request.urlopen('somewebsite3').read()
```

I have the following data:

```
In [14]:print(x1)
b'<li><span class="Price down2">0.071&nbsp;</span></li>'

In [15]:print(x2)
b'<li><span class="Price up2">0.059&nbsp;</span></li>'

In [16]:print(x3)
b'<li><span class="Price down2">0.079&nbsp;</span></li>'
```

The datatypes of x1, x2 and x3 are bytes. I want to extract 0.071, 0.059, 0.079 as floats from x1, x2 and x3. What's the pythonic way to do so?

Thank you in advance

EDIT: for better presentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```py
import re
x1_extracted = re.findall('(?<=>)\d+\.*\d*', x1.decode('utf-8'))
x1_extracted = float(x1_extracted[0])
```

First, you need to decode your bytes sequence (convert it from bytes to string. I'm assuming the encoding is utf-8). Then you can use the `re` module to find the values. Step-by-step, the expression means: Find one or more digits (`\d+`), optionally followed by a dot (`\.*`) and optionally followed by more digits (`\d*`). All that should be preceded by a `>` (`(?<=>)`).

Comment: thank you. It is interesting to know that regex can handle the bytes data and that after the output of regex, it is a list object

Comment: `x1.decode('utf-8')` converts x1 to a string, so it's handling a string, also look at the docs of [findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to learn more about it

Comment: thanks for showing me how to decode a byte type into a string type data